# Self-defined char-array constant typecast to unsigned short?

Tags: c, arrays, c-preprocessor, unsigned-integer

I am trying to convert a self-defined char constant (using `#define` in a header file) holding a Port number, to an unsigned Short int (in order to be able to handle it using htons() to get the network Byte-Order).
I defined a structure in a separate header, grouping PORT, HOSTNAME, and a GAMEKINDNAME (I believe the constants name are pretty self-explanatory; they are all respectively stored as char-arrays).

The specification of the initialized structure looks like this:

```
    struct Config configuration_parameters = {
    .type_of_game = GAMEKINDNAME,
    .hostname = HOSTNAME,
    .port = (unsigned short) PORT
    };
```

While compiling, I get the following errors:

> warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
>           error: initializer element is not constant

I thought that this might be caused by the fact that char uses 1 Byte of storage, while unsigned short uses 2 Bytes of storage, that this might represent some sort of conflict... Is this assumption right, and if so (or even if not), anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why define it as a character constant? If it is a constant and you really need it to be a character constant, define a second `#define PORT_S 80` (replace varname and value with whatever suits) and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your declaration for `PORT` looks more or less like this:

```
const char *PORT = "12345";
```

if you cast that to `unsigned short` you will *not* cast the value, but instead the pointer to `"12345"`. Use a function like atoi to achieve that:

```
struct Config configuration_parameters = {
    .type_of_game = GAMEKINDNAME,
    .hostname = HOSTNAME,
    .port = 0
    };
configuration_parameters.port = (unsigned short)atoi(PORT);
```

Comment: Thank you, that allready helped! Now the error message changed however, I get the following: `config.c:13: error: initializer element is not constant`
`config.c:13: error: (near initialization for ‘configuration_parameters.port’)` where line 13 is the end of the struct , being the final `};`

Comment: Oh sorry. Since atoi is a function, you cannot use it to initialize a struct. If you can initialized `port` with `0` and initialize it the line after? (I'll change the post accordingly)

Comment: If you're initializing the configuration_parameters struct outside of any function, you won't be able to use any function calls to do it. You could define PORT to be an integer (honestly, I'm not sure why you'd define it as a string).